# Сравнить два массива PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Есть таблица MySQL в которой хранятся имена файлов изображений для одного пользователя:

```
+----+------------+
| id | photo_name |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 1.jpg      |
|  2 | 2.jpg      |
|  3 | 3.jpg      |
|  4 | 4.jpg      |
|  5 | 5.jpg      |
+----+------------+
```

Если пользователь добавит еще два изображения 6.jpg и 7.jpg, то со стороны клиента мы получим массив включающий уже 7 изображений(5 было + 2 добавленных), который выглядит следующим образом(используем Jquery UI Sortable):

```
 $ar_img = array('1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg','6.jpg','7.jpg');
```

Каким образом можно добавить в таблицу новые изображения на основе сравнения уже существующих?

Т.е. мне нужно взять массив $ar_img, сравнить состав имен картинок массива с именами картинок, которые имеются в таблице. Если есть изменения, то добавить недостающие в существующую таблицу!

Как это можно сделать средствами MySQL и PHP?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить массив картинок из бд, найти разницу между массивами, и добавить те которых нет:

```
//массив из бд
$old_imgs = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg'];
//массив с новыми картинками
$ar_img = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg', '6.jpg','7.jpg'];
//разница, в массиве diff будут ['6.jpg','7.jpg']
$diff = array_diff($ar_img, $old_imgs);
```